# Which is the model semivariogram for binary data?

Tags: kriging, geostatistical-analyst, variogram

I have a binary data (1,0) to calculate spatial distribution of soil bacteria. I have to use indicator kriging (presence/absence) and fitting model of semivariogram. Then, which is the model semivariogram for binary data?

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever semivariogram works with your data. The problem with indicator kriging can be that because your data is 0s and 1s that the differences that are plotted on the Y axis of a variogram cloud are all 0 or 0.5 - but once you've got enough of those and binned them you should get (for a large number of points) a smooth variogram.